# How can I set default methods to a list like class?

Tags: python

For example, I have two classes Apple and Apples

```
class Apple:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
  def eat(self):
    ...
  def sale(self):
    ...

class Apples:
  def __init__(self, apples: List[Apple]):
    self.apples = apples
```

Is it possible to add below methods for Apples without explicit write them out?

```
  def eat(self):
    for apple in self.apples:
      apple.eat()
  def sale(self):
    for apple in self.apples:
      apple.sale()
```

I want this because there are some large database related operations, like 'select sum(weight) from apple where id in (x, y, z)'. So I would like to have a list like class to unify method works for individual apple (like eat) and this type of operation.

Comment: Why do you have the class at all as opposed to just a list of apples? And, no. You need to write code.

Comment: There are some large database related operations, like 'select sum(weight) from apple where id in (x, y, z)'. So I would like to have a list like class to unify method works for individual apple (like eat) and this type of operation.

Comment: _There are some large database related operations, like 'select sum(weight) from apple where id in (x, y, z)'. So I would like to have a list like class to unify method works for individual apple (like eat) and this type of operation._ Can you be more specific?

Comment: I can have a weight method in Apple with query 'select weight from apple where id = {self.id}' and sum up in list, but this will query same table multiple times which is not efficiency. In the meantime I also have other job won't improve efficiency to do in batch, so I prefer do it in Apple level to keep the logic simple, and just simply loop over each Apple in Apples.

Comment: _but this will query same table multiple times which is not efficiency._ There are plenty of ways of improving DB performance though, and I'm still not sure how the code you presented will improve efficiency/performance.

Comment: You wrote _So I would like to have a list like class to unify method works for individual apple (like eat) and this type of operation_, which makes me think you're going to end up essentially rewriting your database software. There are no doubt plenty of better ways of doing this.